# Update from 4.5 to 4.6 failing

Tags: database, wpdb, updates

I am having a few issues upgrading a wordpress installation. I am moving from 4.5.3 to the latest, 4.6.1 - but every time I try I get an error. I have tried both the auto-update and doing it manually but each time the database appears to become corrupted.

When I did a manual update (copying over the files), I went to login and had a message to update my database. I clicked the ok button and then got the following error.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

[image]

Comment: Have you clicked 'continue'?

Comment: Is this the codex guide you followed to update manually: <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update">Manual Update</a>

Comment: Yep that's the guide I followed. I did read elsewhere that it might be due to plugins so made sure they were disabled during the upgrade.

If I click continue I am taken to the dashboard, which appears fine and seems to work - but I am missing some data (for example my menus are gone and some posts too).